# Associating a constant value over time with predictor variables

Tags: mixed-model, inference, model-selection

Question: How do you model a static response variable (change between baseline and final timepoint) with a variable that changes over time?

Background: A person's inflammation levels are measured at 0, 6, and 20 weeks. Inflammation may have increased or decreased over time. Here is some toy data to demonstrate. As you can see, I calculate the total change in the value, which is then held constant at the ID level.

```
set.seed(123)
exampleDT <- data.table(ID = rep(c(1,2,3,4,5), each = 3), 
Time.weeks = rep(c(0,6,20), 5),  ProteinI = rnorm(15, mean = 50, sd = 10), 
                        Inflammation = sample(1:50, 15, replace = TRUE))
exampleDT[, `:=`(Inflammation.change = Inflammation[Time.weeks == 20] - Inflammation[Time.weeks == 0], 
                 Baseline.inflammation = Inflammation[Time.weeks == 0]), by = ID]

> head(exampleDT)
   ID Time.weeks ProteinI Inflammation Inflammation.change Baseline.inflammation
1:  1          0 33.13307           30                  13                    30
2:  1          6 58.37787            6                  13                    30
3:  1         20 51.53373           43                  13                    30
4:  2          0 38.61863            8                  14                     8
5:  2          6 62.53815           22                  14                     8
6:  2         20 54.26464           22                  14                     8
```

Hypothesis: The reduction in inflammation (calculated between week 0 and 20) is associated with changes to ProteinI level. The bigger the inflammation reduction, the steeper the increase in the level of ProteinI over time.

My first thought was that I could model this with linear mixed models. In `lme4` syntax, I thought to model this as:

> Inflammation.change ~ ProteinI*Time.weeks + Baseline.inflammation + (1|ID)

The model fails to converge (see output pasted below). I'm not sure but I think issue here is that the Inflammation.change status is constant for each time point at the patient level.

If decide on a threshold for the response variable and gave it a binary value (Inflammation.improvement = 0,1), then I could use mixed effects logistic regression, but I want to keep all available information for this model.

```
> lmer(Inflammation.change ~ ProteinI*Time.weeks + (1|ID), exampleDT)
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: Inflammation.change ~ ProteinI * Time.weeks + (1 | ID)
   Data: exampleDT
REML criterion at convergence: -118.603
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Std.Dev. 
 ID       (Intercept) 1.156e+01
 Residual             6.406e-07
Number of obs: 15, groups:  ID, 5
Fixed Effects:
        (Intercept)             ProteinI           Time.weeks  ProteinI:Time.weeks  
          1.000e+01            4.575e-15            2.425e-14           -4.779e-16  
optimizer (nloptwrap) convergence code: 0 (OK) ; 0 optimizer warnings; 2 lme4 warnings 
Warning messages:
1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  unable to evaluate scaled gradient
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 1 negative eigenvalues
3: In as_lmerModLT(model, devfun) :
  Model may not have converged with 1 eigenvalue close to zero: 1.2e-11
```

Edit: For what it's worth, I'm interested in making inferences based on my output rather than actually predicting the change, so I wondered if I could switch the response and predictor, i.e.

> ProteinI ~ Inflammation.change*Time.weeks + Baseline.inflammation + (1|ID)

On my actual data, this runs without singularity issues. Is that a reasonable workaround? I have included Baseline.inflammation here because in the real data, if you have high baseline inflammation then your inflammation reduction is more likely to be larger so I try to account for this in the model.

Comment: Please mark where you have edited, so that people can understand the flow of question and answer.  You could put your new model at the end of your post, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your title question is: You don't.

Later, you write:

> I'm not sure but I think issue here is that the Inflammation.change
> status is constant for each time point at the patient level.

Yes. That is correct. If you want to look at inflammation change as your DV, then you don't want and can't use a MLM. You could model it as related to any of your IVs, although if you include multiple time points, you are going to have issues with collinearity and also some philosophical issues -- if the change is from time 1 to time 3, then including time 2 or time 3 is problematic. I would suggest including only time 1.

But a much better method is to use and MLM and use *inflammation* as the DV. This is what MLMs are designed to do (at least in longitudinal contexts).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I edited the post and I wonder what you think of this model as an alternative: ProteinI ~ Inflammation.change*Time.weeks + Baseline.inflammation + (1|ID)? I would report the interaction term from the model (i.e, Inflammation.change:Time.weeks)

Comment: That completely changes the meaning.  It seems like you randomly switched the DV to make the model work. 

Does inflammation depend on protein, or vice versa?  

Also,  your new model violate temporality.  Things can't depend on things that come after them